# Sitecore media library - implications of sharing direct links with third parties

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

If I am sharing a media item hosted in Sitecore in the following format

```
<domain>/~/media/<guid>.ashx
```

are there implications that I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

There might be few issues like

1. It's not the url which would be generated by Sitecore. It means that same media item will be accessible using multiple urls.
2. This format is not user friendly - no one will remember which guid states which item.
3. If someone attaches another image in media library to a media item, 3rd party applications will not be notified in any way that there is a new image for a given link.

There may be other issues as well.

From the security perspective it should not be a problem if you expose ids of your items.